# Strikeout Chars with QTextCharFormat

Tags: pyqt, qtextedit, pyside6

I am currently writing a editor with pyside6 and use qtextedit as main widget. The editor shall give the users the opportunity to mark mistakes in texts by colored lines over/under the normal black text (underline and strikeout). Underline can easily be colored by setUnderlineColor(), but strikeout cannot be colored. I tried with cursors and brushes, but with no effect. My questions are:

1. Is coloring strikeout possible at all?
2. Can qtextedit widgets be "overpainted"? How to retrieve the absolut positions of cursors in absolute coordinates?

Comment: The answer to your first question is no, as Qt doesn't provide such feature. The answer to the first part of your second is yes, since QTextEdit is a QWidget and any custom painting can be done. Anyway, consider that on StackOverflow you should only ask one question per post. Working with QTextDocuments is not an easy task, as it requires deep studying on their structure and behavior. If the second question is related to the strikeout matter, I suggest you to start by reading the documentation about QTextBlock and its [`layout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html#layout).

Comment: I am sorry for posting more than one question, but I can mark anything in color that I need except the strikeout, which is necessary for marking consistency. In Latex, where I have a lot of experience, this is all easy. Thank you for the QTextBlock information.

Comment: LaTeX is a much more advanced text layout system, Qt's rich text engine is powerful, but limited to basic features also for performance reasons, as it's used in almost any QWidget that displays text. If you're able to create a suitable implementation, I suggest you to post your own answer. Consider that, for better modularity, you should probably implement the strikeout support on a QTextDocument subclass and not on the QTextEdit: this will make that feature more portable, allowing, for instance, printing support. See [`drawContents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#drawContents)

Answer (score 0):

As of qt 6.2 (tested with pyside6) colored strikeout is now possible in the editor. compose a format with `setUnderlineColor()` and then `setFontStrikeOut()`, then merge formats. it is now even there in html and odf exports.